# Analytics receives events, but does not log them in reporting

Tags: google-analytics

I've been all over google and SO looking for answers here. I've checked code against google's tracking code suggestions and I've even tested with their [sample code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide). But I cannot get the events to be properly tracked in Google Analytics. My code has been live on the site for some time (~ a month), so this should have overcome any lag on the reports there.

I'm using analytics, the async version, which works fine for page tracking and other 'normal' features. Trying to set up event tracking, I followed the example, and waited a week. Still nothing. I've been debugging and I'm not having any of the 'normal' problems (as far as I can see).

So:

Example tracking code fired:

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']);">Play</a>
```

This triggers an event, which according to ga_debug.js, is fired successfully. Checking the network panel I can see the  request and _umt.gif returns status 200.

I've checked the request string in there. All seems good.

But checking GA, there is nothing in the reports. ***But*** when you go to GA Realtime > Events, you can see the events being fired!?

I can trigger the events on page or fire them from the console and corresponding events show up in the realtime section, but they have no data (Category, Action or Label).

This is odd, that even firing Google's own [example code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) nothing is showing up.

If anyone has any ideas of where to start debugging for this (or has experience of anything similar), it would be great to hear.

[image: What I see in the realtime event tracking screen: No data!]

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, but using the Measurement Protocol.

Comment: @Brian Let me know if you have any joy. I'm still utterly stumped by this.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I've only had it for an hour or so. Not sure how much should I wait until the events show up in reporting, maybe I get lucky and there is just a lag.

Comment: So this seems to be solved for me. I'm not sure what fixed it. We'd had another issue with an update that broke analytics all together. we weren

Comment: So this is fixed for me. I'm not sure why. A separate issue that prevented us accessing the _gaq global variable came up. When I fixed this and implemented it across the board everything started working. So that *could* have something to do with it. Though right now, I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this issue for three days. I know this thread is old, but I stumbled upon it during my searching. I wanted to post what my personal resolution was in case someone else comes across this.

My Solution:

Here is where I finally found it:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables

Under: "Using Custom Variables" > "Traditional (ga.js) Snippet" (We are using the ga.js still... for now.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and ran into this issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35353093

In summary, I was setting the userId property via below.  Removing that started historical tracking for me.

```
ga('set', 'userId', username);
```

Answer (score -2):

This question gets asked a lot and the answer is almost always "Google Analytics standard SLA is 24 hours". The logs are processed in batch behind the scenes. At peak times, this takes a while.

> It can take up to 24 hours for the Google Analytics servers to update -- [Source: Google Documentation - Check your web tracking code setup](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008083?hl=en)

Comment: As I said, I waited at least a week before I decided to come here. It ended up being about a month in the end before the results started being logged by Google.

Comment: I can only assume there was a problem on the Google end of things as it cleared itself up without any changes from me in the end. We just lost a month of results.

Comment: OP says that he waited more than a week to see data. Long beyond the SLA.